# How do I debug promise-based code in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, promise

I am using Cujo's great [When](https://github.com/cujojs/when/wiki/Examples#whendefer) library to provide a Promises/A+ implementation for my Node project, although this question is not node-specific.

Generally, When's great: it lets me write more maintainable, readable code.

However, when my callbacks fail unexpectedly (accessing a property of a null variable, etc), the exceptions are effectively swallowed by When, as seems to be [specified](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/#point-50) by the Promises/A+ spec. Unfortunately, this means **I don't get any feedback about the error** (other than the callback stops executing at that point). No error type or message, no line number.

To illustrate:

```
// hypothetical asynchronous database query
database.query(queryDetails).then(function(result) {

  var silly = 3.141592654;
  silly(); // TypeError: number is not a function!

  process(result); // this code is silently never executed

});
```

I can think of a handful of (unacceptable) ways to tackle this:

- providing failure callbacks for every `then` call (to dump the reason/exception to the console)
- wrapping all callback bodies in try-catches
- littering the codebase with "landmark logs" ala `console.log('I got here 123')`

Am I just doing it wrong? Surely I'm not alone in finding the debuggability of promises-based code poor. Is there an obvious solution I'm missing?

Comment: Prefer [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) to when. It has _AMAZING_ stack traces (much much better). Oh and don't worry about performance it's also much faster. Also, bluebird logs unhandled excpetions to stderr (to the console usually) with full stack traces. It also has very nice error handling with catch and such.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin - is that an answer?

Comment: No, that's a library suggestion after dealing with the issue myself. Library suggestions are bad answers :) I'm not sure if "When" has a good unhandledExceptionHandler. In all honesty, compared to Bluebird all the other libraries for promises in Node seem very very naive.

Comment: unhandledExceptionHandler!! Just reading about it now, it has a "monitor". It's so weird that this problem isn't handled by the Promises/A+ spec ...

Comment: Promises/A+ spec isn't about making a practical promise implementation   (it doesn't even specify a way to create a promise) but minimal requirements for good interop.

Comment: I know it may be boring, but onError callbacks are a similar to catch blocks on syncronuous programming, and providing catchless try blocks are known bad practice

Comment: @pedroassis yep, I just dislike the heavy nesting that comes with "traditional" (node style) callbacks. I am a fan of promises' "catch", and always use it at least once in a chain.

Comment: @aaaidan that what I mean, you should provide the onError callbacks to your promises, unless they are runtime exceptions, if they are you will need a promise implementation that have a good debugging

Comment: @pedroassis Yeah, that's the thing, the main point of this question is those troublesome runtime errors, which are particularly common in the first cut of code.

Comment: Summed comments up with additional data and `when` specific solution to an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update Sep 2016:** NodeJS 6.6.0+ and 7.0+ will warn automatically on unhandled rejections. Run node with `--trace-warnings` to get reasonable stack traces. Still not as good as what bluebird gives you but a lot better than the situation before.

---

Ok, so summing up the information from the comments and add some.

- There is nothing in the Promises/A+ specification that dictates how to deal with this problem. The specification is about the minimal requirements for good interop between different promise libraries - so one promise library can consume promises created in another and vice versa.
- Several libraries solve this problem by including a `.done` method that explicitly declares the chain has ended, this causes uncaught rejections to be thrown. Libraries like When and Q solve the problem this way. For example if your `.then` after `.query` was a `.done` you'd get a long stack trace.
- Newer, less naive implementations of promises like Bluebird solve this problem by automatically figuring out possibly uncaught rejections and logging them out for you loudly. They also give you a hook. When has experimental support for this using the monitor.

As such:

```
 require('when/monitor/console'); // when will now log async rejections used with
                                  // `then` , this is experimental in when.
```

With bluebird

```
Promise.longStackTraces(); // Bluebird always logs async rejections but with this 
                           // option it will stitch the asynchronous context stack
                           // for you in your methods.
```

- ES6 promises' behavior is unspecified on this. There is no explicit requirements on the native implementations with regards to this. However, I know vendors are working on it and I'd expect engines to start figuring this out even in native implementations.

Comment: Why the hell is this not on by default?! Also even if I enable this, I get no line number or error stacktrace. How am I supposed to find where did it happen?

Comment: @Tomas it is on by default, -and you can log to a file, all these features take hundreds of hours - and we could really use some help with improving tooling. Apologies for the bad default, when I started working on it the event didn't exist and exceptions were just swallowed, after that we added the event - and then in 6.6 the trace by default. V8 adds util.promisify, async_hooks support and better traces - we're working on improving things but this is just a hobby for most of us. Still, sorry for the shitty debugging experience!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But really, all I needed to do was to catch the exception and print the stacktrace. The code that warns about unhandled exception clearly catches it, so it could just as well print the stacktrace while you're catching it anyway? Anyway thanks for being so dedicated to this. I am of course grateful for Node.js and everything in it, it's my most favourite platform for many things I do!

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I detect when a Promise has been rejected on Node but not caught:

```
if (typeof process === 'object') {
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (error, promise) => {
        console.error("== Node detected an unhandled rejection! ==");
        console.error(error.stack);
    });
}
```

In addition to that, you could use this [monkey wrapper to provide long stack traces for Node's ES6 Promises](https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/8c357b8a4ac6803a0f188d495901b6bc). It produces similar output to Q's `longStackSupport`.  I would not recommend it for use outside of development code, due to performance concerns.  (It's working for me in Node v4.4.1.  I have not yet tested it in Chrome or Firefox.)

Comment: This answer helped me to detect undefined functions in promises.